# Cordova iOS - how to change minimum deployment version?

Tags: ios, cordova

I've got cordova v6.0.0 and a test device that is iOS 7.1.2

Based on what I read, cordova v4.0.0 was updated to use minimum deployment target iOS 8

Is there anything I can do, either in or out of Xcode, to force this to deploy to my iOS 7.1.2 test device?

Comment: You might be able to set the deployment target to iOS 7 but that does not mean that Cordova will work. If Cordova call any methods that are not available on iOS 7 your app will crash.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can add the deployment-target preference to your project's config.xml. For example, this would set the deployment target to iOS 7.1.2.

```
<preference name="deployment-target" value="7.1.2" />
```

Since this is below Cordova's minimum supported version, there is no guarantee this will work.

Comment: works fine with phonegap cli-5.2.2 (cordova-ios 3.9.1) too

Answer (score 4):

You can add the **deployment-target** as a preference in config in your **plugin.xml**

```
  <config-file parent="/*" target="config.xml">
        <feature name="<pluign name>">
            <param name="ios-package" value="plugin name"/>
        </feature>
        <preference name="deployment-target" value="12.0" />
        <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
    </config-file>
```

Answer (score 1):

Cordova iOS 4.0.0 does in fact target iOS 8 by default. This means your app will only be installable on iOS devices running 8.0 or greater. You can go into Xcode and change this setting. Click on your project name, then the General tab, and under Deployment Info you will see a Deployment Target drop down.