# How to change default settings of Ionic build ios command?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-ios

I have setup a gulp process to deploy my ionic application. Using gulp process I run **ionic build ios** to make build or **cordova build ios --device** to generate ipa, but it makes my build/IPA with default setting always which results in increased IPA size(almost 10-12 MB) and takes more time to upload/download to iTunes, for e.g

- Target - 8.0 (Should be 6.0)
- Device - Universal (Need to change this to iPhone only)
- View Mode - Not specific (I want to set this to portrait only) are default settings which I want to modify.

We can change settings through XCode, but I want to take charge of all this setting on command line. Is there any possible way to make this happen? or are there any command which takes such parameters?

Please help..!!

Comment: Check this : https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/

Comment: Thanks @HardikVaghani, I checked link, I hope it will solve my problem... can you please add this as answer to question.... so I can accept it..!!

Comment: Posted my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this article. It has all the configuration related to cordova project which is mainly handled by `config.xml`.

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/

> `<preference name="deployment-target" value="7.1.2" />`

Refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27135185/how-can-i-specify-the-minimum-sdk-in-phonegap-it-is-ignoring-android-minsdkvers) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36806063/6449750) too.

Regards.