# Invalid iOS Simulator deployment target

Tags: xcode, cordova, cocoapods, cordova-ios

After freshly installing my project on a new Mac M1 machine (might be unrelated), upon running `cordova build`, I'm facing a series of "unsupported deployment target version" messages:

```
project-path/cordova/platforms/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'FirebaseAnalytics' from project 'Pods')
project-path/cordova/platforms/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'FirebasePerformance' from project 'Pods')
project-path/cordova/platforms/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'GoogleAppMeasurement' from project 'Pods')
project-path/cordova/platforms/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'GoogleSignIn' from project 'Pods')
project-path/cordova/platforms/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'Firebase' from project 'Pods')
project-path/cordova/platforms/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'GoogleUtilities' from project 'Pods')
project-path/cordova/platforms/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'GoogleDataTransport' from project 'Pods')
project-path/cordova/platforms/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'nanopb' from project 'Pods')
project-path/cordova/platforms/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'FirebaseRemoteConfig' from project 'Pods')
project-path/cordova/platforms/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'FirebaseMessaging' from project 'Pods')
project-path/cordova/platforms/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'FirebaseInstanceID' from project 'Pods')
project-path/cordova/platforms/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'FirebaseInstallations' from project 'Pods')
project-path/cordova/platforms/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'FirebaseCrashlytics' from project 'Pods')
project-path/cordova/platforms/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'FirebaseCoreDiagnostics' from project 'Pods')
project-path/cordova/platforms/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'FirebaseCore' from project 'Pods')
project-path/cordova/platforms/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'FirebaseAuth' from project 'Pods')
project-path/cordova/platforms/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'FirebaseABTesting' from project 'Pods')
project-path/cordova/platforms/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'AppAuth' from project 'Pods')
** BUILD FAILED **
```

I tried declaring specific target version to `10.0` as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61887718/592641) with no success.

- My Cordova version is `10.0.0`.
- My cordova-ios version is `6.2.0`.

Comment: you just have to set your application deployment to greater than or equal to 9.0 https://stackoverflow.com/a/36806063/6299120. If you open ios/podfile then "platform :ios, '8.0'" is the issue. Make sure it changes after you edit config file and build the app.

Comment: @Samin dude.. that's exactly what I noted as not working in my question

Comment: Sorry for that. Can you try updating the ios/podfile platform version to 10.0 -> then go to ios folder from terminal and "pod install" -> Then run the project directly from xcode (.xcworkspace file)

Comment: That'll probably work, but it's not a viable option for me, as I need my setup to work on a remote deployment machine. What you're suggesting will require an additional script that changes the contents inside `/platforms/ios`. I'd rather figure out a straightforward approach.